# Python Selenium Can't find element/click radiobutton

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, bots

New to Python and Selenium. I am trying to select a radiobutton:

However, the name,id, and xpath are all non-locatedable. When I use the values in the html with `find_element_by_()`. I assume they are being generated by something.

for example: `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSR_DUMMY_RECV1$sels$0$$0"]')`

I can't share the url since its part of a login site, but here is the html of the element I am trying to access:

returns **error** that the web element cannot be found.

How else can I locate this object? I have tried `send_keys.(KeyS.TAB)` and `(Keys.ENTER)` to click this button. However this method does not seem to work with checking radiobuttons. I have tried using keys.SPACE to check a radiobutton but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML or URL of this application?

Comment: share web url or html,so that we can help

Comment: I can't share the url since its part of a login site, but here is the html of the element I am trying to access:

<input class="PSRADIOBUTTON" type="radio" name="SSR_DUMMY_RECV1$sels$0" id="SSR_DUMMY_RECV1$sels$0$$0" tabindex="153" value="0" onclick="javascript:onClickRadio(this, event);" psnchg="0" title="Select this row">